# What is the equivalent of jQuery $.extend() in Ember.js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ember.js, clone

I used to clone a variable in jquery like this:

```
var clone = $.extend(true, {}, orig);
```

Is there any method in Ember.js that is equivalent to this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes there is:    [Ember.copy](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.html#method_copy)

```
var clonedObj = Ember.copy(originalObj, true);
```

Answer (score 18):

That's like my least favorite named method in jquery.  Every time I want to merge two objects it takes me a few seconds of trying to think of what it's called.  You can also use `assign` in Ember.

```
Ember.assign({first: 'Tom'}, {last: 'Dale'}); // {first: 'Tom', last: 'Dale'}
var a = {first: 'Yehuda'}, b = {last: 'Katz'};
Ember.assign(a, b); // a == {first: 'Yehuda', last: 'Katz'}, b == {last: 'Katz'}
```

or in your case

```
Ember.assign({}, orig);
```

http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.html#method_assign

But, you should note, it doesn't support deep cloning like copy does.

Comment: Ember.merge() seems to be [deprecated](https://github.com/emberjs/data/issues/4233) (although it doesn't say so in the docs), use [assign()](http://emberjs.com/api/#method_assign) instead

Comment: Updated, thanks for letting me know, I didn't realize they'd deprecated that.

Comment: merge is still working for me (2.5), but assign takes n objects to merge, where merge only takes 2.